# Breaking the content of a page after certain height in creating pdf from html

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to create pdf from the HTML template created using Python and Django. The data which I want to display is like every page is for 1 client and the page consists of a table. In some cases the table data is large, and I have fixed the height of each page as 700px. The issue is when the table is large for some specific clients then the table crosses over to the next page and overlaps with the table data of other clients. I want to achieve something like if the table data is large for a client then the next page should have the data for the same client and then for other clients next page onwards.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my pdfs, in between each page:

```
 <div class="page-break"></div>
```

with the following css:

```
.page-break { 
  display: block; 
  page-break-before: always; 
}
```

You can read about `page-break-before` here:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before

Comment: I think using this will not bring the table headers on the next page.  I want like if the data is beyond the one page the next page should display the remaining data with the table header s well

Comment: No it wont but that you didnt really ask for that in the question. You should amend the question to include that info.